# How do i use the fixed sized integers from 'cstdint' lib to store/pack bit data sequence with maximum length of 250MB? Why to not use normal int?

Tags: c++, sequence, bit

In the condition of the task that I am doing, I am specifically told:
"Integers in C++ do not have a fixed size. To access integers with a fixed size, you can use the library cstdint."
I take it it is recommended that I use fixed-sized integers for packing of bit data (max 250MB). I am failing to understand how does fixed-sized int help in this case? And how do I use those fixed-sized integers? I imagine I should probably declare a structure, but I am not at all sure.
Thank you!

Comment: I think what they mean is the size of int for example is not guaranteed to be a specific size (according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types int is "at least 16 bits"). If you want exactly 32 bit int, for example, you cant use std::(u)int32_t type alias.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I also gathered as much, like it is stated.. that the integers are normally not guaranteed size. But I could not understand why do I need a specifically fixed size in this situation. As @Gabbergabbo have written in his comment it appears that if you don't know what architecture the software would run on you need to make sure to allocate fixed space. At least that is what I understand from his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers in c++ are not fixed size in that they can have different sized based on arch or other environment variables (OS, compiler, etc.)

The library cstdint exposes data type that are guaranteed to be fixed in size, for example the type int8_t is guaranteed to be 8 bit long, and you can use uint8_t to read/write your data.

Example in reading to/from a file

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    //writing
    uint8_t value = '8';
    std::ofstream myoutputfile;
    myoutputfile.open("filename");
    myoutputfile << value << std::endl;
    myoutputfile.close();
    
    //reading
    std::ifstream myinputfile;
    myinputfile.open("filename");
    uint8_t c;
    myinputfile >> c;
    std::cout << c;
    myinputfile.close();
    return 0;
    
}
```

if i wanted to write a small (<100KB) quantity of data i'd do something like:

```
uint8_t data[5] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };

//writing
myoutputfile.open("filename");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myoutputfile << data[i];
}
myoutputfile.close();

//reading
myinputfile.open("filename");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myinputfile >> data[i];
    std::cout << data[i];
}
myinputfile.close();
```

Comment: Hello.  Thank you a lot for your input and for the snippet.  I have more questions though if you don't mind?  Reading the code it is reading from a file.  I would have to cut or add data at specific places in the sequence? I mean is it okay if I define a fixed-sized integer and use bitwise operators to write in it? Also if I have to store up to 250MB sequence, does it mean a struct with multiple fixed-sized integers is supposed to be declared or I am not thinking in the right direction? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: @samuraiJackDavidson storing that much data in a struct seems like suicide to me if you're going to use only 8 bit integers :D think about storing that data in the heap (something like using malloc/free). I have updated my answer to show you how to write/read some continuous data

Comment: Okay, I can see what you mean by suicide. Thanks a lot for the other example you have written. They mention in the condition of the task - array of integers (your example seems like what they mean), and double-linked pointer list. Both with self-selectable integer type as arguments. So I can use the fixed-sized integers from "cstdint" like any other integer or value type? There is nothing strict or problematic that I should be worried about them like in the syntax or something? It is unlikely to get an error when I write functions and declarations, just because it's not a standard int?

Comment: @samuraiJackDavidson generally there are no problems to using cstdint types. just define your functions and call them with data of the same type to avoid possible side-effects and you're good to go! Have fun programming ;)

Comment: Thanks! You helped a lot. I just could not find very specific information online about actually using this lib, at least not in such a scenario. And I definitely needed to know and to be sure how to work with it in order to use it. Have a good one!